# How to compare tables

Tags: c

I come here to seek some help in an algorithm issue
We've got a reference tab, tab_ref.

We've got other comparative tabs, all of these are float.

The aim is to find which one is the "closest" to tab_ref, I don't really know how to explain it so here is a little example:

```
float tab_ref[] = {1, 2, 5, 3, 4}                float tab1[] = {1, 3, 5, 2, 1}     float tab2[] = {8, 9, 3, 9, 7}
```

tab_ref is so closer to tab1, comparing all the values together.

Edit: Sorry to have first post in French, it's my first time here and I somehow thought it was one of my regular French forums, my bad

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, not incomplete code. `tab_ref = {1, 2, 5, 3, 4} tab1 = {1, 3, 5, 2, 1} tab2 = {8, 9, 3, 9, 7}` is not compilable code.

Comment: Okay here we go : float tab_ref[5] = {1 , 2, 5, 3, 4} float tab1 = {1, 3, 5, 2, 1} float tab2 = {8, 9, 3, 9, 7}. And we're gonna try to find out which one the "closest" to tab_ref comparing all the values

Comment: Sorry, please edit the question, not drip feed information.

Comment: `closest` you mean by having most elements in common?

Comment: A reasonable starting point would be to evaluate the sum of the square of the differences between the terms in two tables, and accept the one from the compare set which minimises that value. There is considerable statistical justification for that approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate" ? Making a new array with the sum of the square of the differences between terms ? (And sorry Weather, but I the point is that I don't even know the algorithm, so I can't really make a code as an exemple)

Comment: The only thing that come in my mind would be to take the sum of each tables, and to make the difference between them, the smallest would be the closest, but I'm not sure at all if it's mathematically correct

Answer (score 0):

Compute a "norm" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)
of the difference between your two arrays. Use whatever norm is the most appropriate based on your definition of "closeness".  Minimize the norm.